# Remove NA from list of list and preserve structure in R

Tags: r, list, na

Here is my example.

```
test <- list(el_1 = data.frame(col_1 = c(1,2), col_2 = c(2,3)), el_2 = NA)
```

I would like to drop the second element of the list.

Here is what I tried.

```
test_1 <- sapply(test, function(x) x[!is.na(x)], simplify = F)
test_2 <- sapply(test, function(x) !is.na(x), simplify = F)
test_3 <- unlist(test)
```

None of them worked, in every case I dataframe gets converted to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
test[!sapply(test, function(x) all(is.na(x)))]
$el_1
  col_1 col_2
1     1     2
2     2     3
```

Answer (score 1):

One way can be:

```
#Code
test[-which(names(test) %in% names(which(is.na(unlist(test)))))]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Filter` in `base R`

```
Filter(function(x) any(!is.na(x)), test)
#$el_1
#  col_1 col_2
#1     1     2
#2     2     3
```

---

Or with `keep` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
keep(test, ~ any(!is.na(.x)))
#$el_1
#  col_1 col_2
#1     1     2
#2     2     3
```

Comment: I guess key here is `any`